# Sobrecarga C++ (objeto + class), (objeto + int), (int + objeto)

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Para un ejercicio necesito realizar operaciones entre int y una clase que he definido (Racional)

```
int main(){
    Racional *r1 = new Racional(1,2);
    Racional *r2 = new Racional(2,3);
    Racional *r;
    // y debo poder hacer las siguientes operaciones:
    r = *r1 + *r2;
    r = *r1 + 52;
    r = *10 + *r2;
}
```

Implemente la clase de la siguiente manera y me da el error 'multiple definition of `operator+(Racional&, Racional&)`'

```
class Racional{
private:
    int numerador;
    int denominador;
public:
    Racional* suma(Racional *);
    // y otras funciones...
};

Racional* operator +(Racional &r1, Racional &r2){
    return r1.suma(&r2); 
}
Racional* operator +(Racional r1, int i){
    Racional *r2 = new Racional(i);
    Racional *ret = r1.suma(r2);
    delete r2;
    return ret;
}
Racional* operator +(int i,Racional r1){
    Racional *r2 = new Racional(i);
    Racional *ret = r1.suma(r2);
    delete r2;
    return ret;
}
```

¿Como debería hacer para poder hacer las operaciones?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Vas por buen camino, pues entiendes los dos tipos de sobrecargas:

1. **Sobrecarga como método de clase**, cuando el operador es un método de la propia clase:

   ```
   struct Ejemplo {
       Ejemplo operator+(int);
   };
   ```

   En este caso, la clase **siempre** estará  la izquierda del operador y el `tipo_t` a la derecha:

   ```
   Ejemplo e;
   Ejemplo a = e + 1; // Correcto
   Ejemplo b = 1 + e; // ERROR!!!
   ```
2. **Sobrecarga como función libre**, cuando el operador es una función libre:

   ```
   struct Ejemplo {
       Ejemplo operator+(int);
   };

   Ejemplo operator+(int, Ejemplo);
   ```

   En este caso puedes elegir los tipos a la izquierda y derecha del operador:

   ```
   Ejemplo e;
   Ejemplo a = e + 1; // Correcto, llama a Ejemplo Ejemplo::operator+(int);
   Ejemplo b = 1 + e; // Correcto, llama a Ejemplo operator+(int, Ejemplo);
   ```

Lo que no entiendes es que **NO** debes usar punteros para nada de lo que necesitas hacer:

#### Propuesta:

Haz que todos los operadores sean funciones libres

```
class Racional {
    friend Racional operator+(const Racional &, const Racional &);
    friend Racional operator+(int, const Racional &);
    friend Racional operator+(const Racional &, int);
};

int main(){
    Racional r1 = Racional(1,2);
    Racional r2 = Racional(2,3);
    Racional r;

    // y debo poder hacer las siguientes operaciones:
    r = r1 + r2; // Primer caso, Racional + Racional
    r = r1 + 52; // Segundo caso, Racional + int
    r = 10 + r2; // Tercer caso, int + Racional
}

Racional operator+(const Racional &, const Racional &) {
    // Código primer caso
}
Racional operator+(int, const Racional &) {
    // Código segundo caso
}
Racional operator+(const Racional &, int) {
    // Código tercer caso
}
```

Dado que `Racional` es una clase, para que los operadores tengan acceso a los datos de la clase, deberán ser funciones amigas de la clase.